# Как сделать правильное наложения лого на слайдер?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать правильное наложения лого на слайдер?

Код:

```css
/* Make the image fully responsive */
.carousel-inner img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.header_slider {
 
}

.container_header {
 width: 1178px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide header_slider " data-ride="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="images/back_header.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="images/back_header.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="images/back_header.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="container container_header">
    <div class="row row_header">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="images/grand_logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как например с помощью `position: absolute`:

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
}

.container_header {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: ;
}

.logo-img {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  

<div class="slider">
  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide header_slider " data-ride="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" alt="Los Angeles"  class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" alt="Chicago" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" alt="New York" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container container_header">
    <div class="row row_header">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://freelance.today/uploads/images/00/07/43/2016/03/18/62de43.jpg" alt="" class="logo-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```